# Handsontable - slow paste

Tags: javascript, jquery, handsontable

When I try pasting large amounts of data into **handsontable** it is very slow at taking in the data to the point that sometimes I get an unresponsive script warning for the `jquery.js` file. Is there a way to make is go any faster? The dataset I am using right now is ~1600 rows and 5 columns.

Here is the link to the table I am trying to paste in currently http://wiki.stat.ucla.edu/socr/index.php/SOCR_Data_Dinov_042108_Antarctic_IceThicknessMawson

Thanks

Comment: This should be solved once Handsontable implements virtual rendering. That should happen during next 30 days. See this thread: https://github.com/warpech/jquery-handsontable/issues/87

Answer (score -1):

Try upgrading to the [latest version](http://handsontable.com/):

```
http://handsontable.com/
```

This should now be resolved